# jQuery replacement for javascript confirm

Tags: asp.net, jquery, confirm

Let's say I want to prompt the user before allowing them to save a record. So let's assume I have the following button defined in the markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click"></asp:Button>
```

To force a prompt with normal javascript, I could wire the OnClick event for my save button to be something like this (I could do this in `Page_Load`):

```
btnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick",
    "return confirm('are you sure you want to save?');");
```

The confirm call will block until the user actually presses one of the Yes/No buttons, which is the behavior I want. If the user presses 'Yes', then my `btnSave_OnClick` method would be called.

For the jquery dialog that is the equivalent, I tried something like this (see below). But the problem is that unlike javascript confirm(), it's going to get all the way through this function (displayYesNoAlert) and then proceed into my btnSave_OnClick method on the C# side. I need a way to make it "block", until the user presses the Yes or No button, and then return true or false so the btnSave_OnClick will be called or not called depending on the user's answer.

Currently, I just gave up and went with javascript's confirm, I just wondered if there was a way to do it.

```
function displayYesNoAlert(msg, closeFunction) {
    dialogResult = false;

    // create the dialog if it hasn't been instantiated
    if (!$("#dialog-modal").dialog('isOpen') !== true) {

        // add a div to the DOM that will store our message
        $("<div id=\"dialog-modal\" style='text-align: left;' title='Alert!'>").appendTo("body");

        $("#dialog-modal").html(msg).dialog({
            resizable: true,
            modal: true,
            position: [300, 200],
            buttons: {
                'Yes': function () {
                    dialogResult = true;
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                'No': function () {
                    dialogResult = false;
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function () {
                if (closeFunction !== undefined) {
                    closeFunction();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    $("#dialog-modal").html(msg).dialog('open');

}
```

Comment: This is great, and what I am looking for. However my javascript confirm pulls a string for the message. How to append that to the div?

    var where_to_coupon = confirm(pm_info_msg_013);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a callback function that is raised when they click a specific button like Yes. You won't be able to block execution in a script, but also have the UI respond to user actions.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware I can use a callback function, see the 'Yes' section of my displayYesNoAlert function above. But that's not really the behavior I need, because I want my btnSave_Click to be called server side if the user responds 'Yes' to the dialog.

Comment: Could you not just copy the script the button uses to raise the postback and execute that in the callback? Worst case scenario, hide the "real" submit button, and make visible your fake submit button that uses your dialog, which in turn does a $('btnSave').click(); I've executed postbacks at the client programmatically before, but I don't recall how to do it off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

This could be as simple as using your current "save" button to fire off the confirm dialog, then inside of the Confirm dialog have the "yes" button fire the "btnSave_Click" event

I think I misunderstood the question at first...this may be some help to you, although I have not tested it. http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/

Comment: @stephen776 - I'm trying to eliminate the confirm call and replace it with the jquery dialog (refer to question title).

Comment: @dcp Yes I am suggesting having your "Save" button open the Modal Dialog...Then have the "Yes"button in the modal dialog wired to the "btnSave_click" event in the code behind. The "No" button would just close the modal dialog

Comment: @stephen776 - "have the "Yes"button in the modal dialog wired to the "btnSave_click" event in the code behind."  That's the part I am not sure how to do, can you provide an example?

Comment: I added a link to an article that may be of help

Comment: @stephen776 - Yes, I had seen that link, but thanks for posting it. I guess I was hoping there was a simpler way, but it doesn't seem like there is. Thanks again.

Comment: that may be the best way to go and the solution will be reusable accross your application

Answer (score 1):

If you need only one final Confirm Box before moving to final code like for SAVE, then definitely this would help to call that SAVE() function in a callback function for button click. That's fine.

I do have another problem as follows:
I want to use this custom confirm box in a form validation where there may be multiple cases and scenarios for confirmation one after other.

If user said YES to first confirm box, we want to present the second confirm box based on form data conditions.

If user again say YES to this second confirm box, then we may need to present the next confirm box.
Here is the problem, that is not yet possible in these cases..