# Executing OnServerClick Based On JS MessageBox Yes/No Selection

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap with ASP.Net.

**I'm trying to add confirmations to my buttons so that code behind only executes if *Yes* is clicked after alert Message box is displayed.**

```
<link href="_JS/jquery.modal.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="_JS/jquery.modal.theme-xenon.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="_JS/jquery.modal.theme-atlant.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="_JS/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>

<!--......-->

<a href="#" runat="server" id="confirm" onserverclick="confirm_ServerClick1">Confirm</a>

<!--......-->

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $('a#confirm').click(function () {
                modal({
                    type: 'confirm',
                    title: 'Confirm',
                    text: 'Are you sure you want to remove the user from the company?',
                    if (result) {
                        //Proceeds to activate event in code behind - confirm_ServerClick1
                    } else {
                        BootstrapDialog.closeAll();
                    }}
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Is it possible? If so, I'd appreciate any tips.

As of now, it simply executes the the confirm_ServerClick1 event ignoring the JS function - without showing any modal popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return true or false in your JS function. False to stop the execution and true to proceed to the server.

```
   $('#confirm').click( function() { your_code_here; return false; // or true. the result from your popup } );

     $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $('a#confirm').click(function () {
                modal({
                    type: 'confirm',
                    title: 'Confirm',
                    text: 'Are you sure you want to remove the user from the company?',
                    if (result) {
//your logic here
                     return true;
                    } else {
                        BootstrapDialog.closeAll(); return false;

                    }}
                });
            });
        });
```

**EDIT**

See below sample for the default JS confirm. (JS Confirm will block the execution until receiving a result from the dialog). In your case the bootstrap popup will not block the execution you will need to call the server side event from your JS based on the result you've received from your popup. 
If the result was true call server side method like this `document.getElementById("CliendId").click()` or using __doPostBack

```
    <a href="#" runat="server" id="confirm" onclick="return confirmEvent();"  onserverclick="confirm_ServerClick1">Confirm</a>


<!--......-->

<script type="text/javascript">

    function confirmEvent()
    {
        if(confirm("Are you sure?"))
        {
            alert("This will execute server side event");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("I'm not sure!");
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works great as a simple message box, but, what would I have to do to add the modal syling? I mostly do back end server stuff and I have very limited JS knowledge.

Comment: No problem buddy. I didn't get your question. If you are asking about styling the default confirm dialog then no you can't do that. Refer to the "Edit" section.

Comment: Refer to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626093/jquery-replacement-for-javascript-confirm or http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/